# Remove formatting from a string: “(123) 456-7890” => “1234567890” in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a string of phone number with format (123)-(456)-7890 but how can i convert to the following form 1234567890?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSString *numberString = [[mixedString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet]] 
                componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

It will give digits from a string.

Comment: in case if number formatting is not what is expected, you can always use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString as seen in following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638623/uiviewcontentmodescaleaspectfill-not-clipping

Comment: Thanks alot Maulik

Comment: @SivaramYadav : Sure ! you should start accepting the answers.

Answer (score 1):

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` supports also regular expression

```
NSString *phoneNumber = @"(123)-(456)-7890";
NSString *filteredPhoneNumber = [phoneNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[ ()-]" 
                                 withString:@""
                                    options:NSRegularExpressionSearch 
                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, phoneNumber.length)];
NSLog(@"%@", filteredPhoneNumber);
```

Put all characters to be ignored between the brackets in the first parameter.

An alternative regex is `@"[^\\d+]"` which means *ignore all non-digit characters*

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *str = @"(123)-(456)-7890";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"(" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @")" withString:@""];
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"-" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"Output = %@",str);
```

**Output** = 1234567890

Answer (score 0):

You also replacing more character in Single Line of coding using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`

```
NSString *YourString = @"(123)-(456)-7890";
YourString = [[[YourString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"YourString == > %@",YourString);
```

**YourString == > 1234567890**

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
NSString *valString = @"(123)456-7890";

NSString* phoneStr=[[[valString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"phone String %@",phoneStr); // finally you get phone String 1234567890
```

its working for me, hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to work outside the USA, use Google's telephony library. Formatting and extracting phone numbers *is difficult*. I wouldn't even try doing it myself by hand.